RECOVER SOL FROM ATA
I created an ATA for a mint token and initilize the amount of SOL of this ATA with get_min_balance_rent_for_exempt_for_account() function ( amount of SOL ^= 0.002039).
Now I  m tring to recover this 0.002039 in using the payer using for creation but I have this message erreur " keypair-pubkey mismatch". Someone have an idea of the issue ?

I hope that you are familiar with the concept of rent.
The TL;DR is that you need some lamports in your account to remain on the blockchain. Without it, there's no incentive for the validator to keep this state. More on this here https://solana.com/docs/core/fees#rent
To recover this SOL, you'll need to close this account, but to close a token account requires it to have a balance of zero.

Non-native Accounts must have a balance of zero to be closed.

ref: https://spl.solana.com/token#closing-accounts
I'd assume that keypair-pubkey mismatch is a failing signer check where you do not have authority over the account you are trying to close.

Hello Thank a lot for your answer ! Finally I successfully close all the account with balance non native account equal to 0. Know a have about 100 ATA wich don't success to close because there is SPL balance into. How can I proccess ?

from spl.token.instructions import burn, BurnParams                burn_instruction = burn(
BurnParams(
program_id=TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
account=pubkey,
mint=mint_address,
owner=payer.pubkey(),
amount=balance,
) here is the python instruction to burn

You can still close accounts with balance in them but that would essentially burn the tokens. I would recommend selling the tokens or using a tool like sol-incinerator if you're not familiar with coding

Note that you cannot close accounts with a balance, since that would cause the supply in the mint to be incorrect. You have to burn them before closing the account.
